# Flask error: Error in the code while defining functions and app route

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Before defining the RegisterationForm class and LoginForm class the code was working fine but after defining the classes the app.route() and functions giving me an syntax error.
i am attaching both the code snippet and the error message in command prompt server.
Please look at it and try to give me solution with proper explanation so that i learn it is happening.[see the code snippet in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlgYc.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is pretty clear there is missing a closing **)** in your **PasswordField**. If you use Pycharm or VScode the IDE will notify you about syntax code issue
[image]